# How to filter list view using search edittext with JSON url

Tags: android, json, listview

am using edittext for search form `JSON` url datas, i give search field. search each letter type on `editText` filter the `listview`, at same time `listview` reload, if `edittext` empty show all current list. how to that please help me...

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.electronic_main);

    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_search);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayTemplist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            String searchString = search.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                String currentString = arraylist.get(i).get(Electronic.WORKERNAME);
                String currentPlaceString = arraylist.get(i).get(Electronic.LOCATION);
                String currentShopString = arraylist.get(i).get(Electronic.SHOPNAME);



                if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(currentString) ||
                        searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(currentShopString) ||
                        searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(currentPlaceString)) {
                    arrayTemplist.add(arraylist.get(i));

                }
      }
            adapter = new ElectronicAdapter(Electronic.this, arrayTemplist);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet(); // true or false

    if (isInternetPresent) {
        new DownloadJSON().execute();

    } else {

        Intent lost = new Intent(Electronic.this, NetConnection.class);
        startActivity(lost);
    }


}


private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Electronic.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/D0_dGQT");

        try {

            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("eletronics");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                map.put("workername", jsonobject.getString("workername"));
                map.put("shopname", jsonobject.getString("shopname"));
                map.put("experience", jsonobject.getString("experience"));
                map.put("fare", jsonobject.getString("fare"));
                map.put("location", jsonobject.getString("location"));
                map.put("Rating", jsonobject.getString("Rating"));
                map.put("address", jsonobject.getString("address"));
                map.put("workerimage", jsonobject.getString("workerimage"));
                map.put("shopphoto", jsonobject.getString("shopphoto"));
                map.put("cell", jsonobject.getString("cell"));


                arraylist.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean arg) {

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new ElectronicAdapter(Electronic.this, arraylist);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
search=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.serach);
    listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String gh = listview.getTextFilter().toString();
            text.setText(gh);
        }
    });
    listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String searchString = search.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
             Log.d("@w2w2w2w",""+searchString);
             int realtext=searchString.length();
             arrayTemplist.clear();
             for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                    String currentString = arraylist.get(i).get("Name").toString();
                    String currentPlaceString = arraylist.get(i).get("city").toString();
                    String currentShopString = arraylist.get(i).get("landtype").toString();
             if(realtext<=currentString.length()&&realtext<=currentPlaceString.length()&&realtext<=currentShopString.length())
             {


                    if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(currentString.substring(0,realtext)) ||
                            searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(currentShopString.substring(0,realtext)) ||
                            searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(currentPlaceString.substring(0,realtext))) {
                        arrayTemplist.add(arraylist.get(i));
                        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(Edit.this, arrayTemplist);
                        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
             }
             else{

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }


             }}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask

    }
```